# The probability of the first jump occurring after $t$ is always positive

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $\mathbb{S}$ be countable and $\Omega$ be the set of all right continuous functions $\omega:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{S}$. Let $X_t(\omega) = \omega(t)$ denote a continuous Markov chain.

Liggett states in proposition 2.29 that

> Suppose $X(t)$ is a Markov chain, and let $\tau = \inf\{t\geq 0:X_t\ne X_0\}$ be the time of the first jump. Then
>   $$P^x(\tau>t) = e^{-c(x)t}$$
>   for some $c(x)\in [0,\infty]$.

So the problem is that if $c(x) = \infty$, then $P^x(\tau > t)=0$ for all $t>0$. Hence, if we take $t\downarrow 0$, then $P^x(\tau > 0)=0$. But, by right continuity, we have $P^x(\tau > 0)=1$ and we reach a contradiction. Is there something wrong with my logic?

Comment: For the case $c(x)=\infty$, if $\tau$ is the random time to stay in state $x$, it looks like $\tau=0$ with probability 1. So $P[\tau=0]=1$.  I do not follow your sentence "by right continuity $P[\tau>0]=1$" so I do not know how you are obtaining a contradiction.  I also do not follow your first sentence with notation "$X_t(\omega) = \omega(t)$", that notation looks designed to confuse.

Comment: @Michael I'm assuming that $\mathbb{S}$ is countable and thus equipped with the discrete metric (maybe I should've mentioned this). Since $\omega$ is right continuous, there exist $\delta>0$ such that if $0<t<\delta$, then $d(\omega(t),\omega(0))<1/2$. Since the discrete metric $d$ can only be 0 or 1, we see that $\omega(t)=\omega(0)$ for all $0<t<\delta$. Hence, $\tau (\omega) > \delta>0$. SInce this is true for all $\omega \in \Omega$, we see that $P^x(\tau >0)=1$.

Comment: @Michael For the notation, I'm just using the analogy form of the discrete Markov chain $X_n (\omega) = \omega_n$. You can think of it as $X(t,\omega) = \omega(t)$ which is used by Liggett.

Comment: I thought you meant right-continuity of CDF functions $P[X\leq x]$.  You mean of the sample path...Yes I agree that if sample paths are required to be right-continuous then there is a contradiction here with $P[\tau=0]=1$. The case of a transition rate being "infinity" is so unusual though, one would expect some type of singularity or exception in this case.

Comment: By the way I don't know what $X_n(\omega)$ would be for a discrete time Markov chain (DTMC), is $\omega$ supposed to be an outcome of the sample space (which determines all random future values of the DTMC)?  I would represent the state of a DTMC at time step $n$ as $X_n$, and/or perhaps use $\{X_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$.  The $\omega$ stuff seems unusual.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the best way to formulate it, but I think it's easier to introduce the shift map $\theta$ with $X_n (\omega) = \omega_n$. At least in Durrett for DTMC, you assume that the sample space $\Omega = \mathbb{S}^\mathbb{N}$ so that $\omega = (\omega_0,\omega_1,...)$. Hence, the random variable $X_n:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{S}$ is the coordinate map $X_n(\omega) = \omega_n$ and the shift operator $\theta: \Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ can be defined as $(\theta \omega)_n = \omega_{n+1}$.

Comment: Using the shift operator, we can then write the Markov property as $E^x(Y\circ \theta^n |\mathscr{F}_n) = E^{X_n}(Y)$ where $Y:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{S}$ is bounded measurable and $\mathbb{F}_n = \sigma(X_0,X_1,...,X_n)$.

Comment: Sounds like "Markov chain theory made hard."  I suppose the shift operator is supposed to simplify some ergodic results or something. Anyway, I would just consider $c(x) \in [0, \infty)$ rather than $c(x) \in [0, \infty]$.  I don't know what it would mean to stay in a discrete state for time 0 anyway, though it might make sense for uncountably infinite state with continuous sample paths.